# Javascript module pattern wrong result

Tags: javascript

So I'm reading "Javascript The Good Parts".
There's this part where I couldn't get it to work.
Its in Chapter 4, Module.
"0" is returned instead of "Q1000".

```js
var serial_maker = function () {
  var prefix = '';
  var seq = 0;
  
  return {
    set_prefix: function (p) {
      prefix = String(p);
    },
    set_seq: function (s) {
      seq = s;
    },
    gensym: function () {
      var result = prefix + seq;
      seq += 1;
      return result;
    }
  };
};

var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix = ('Q');
seqer.set_seq = (1000);
console.log(seqer.gensym());
```

Comment: `seqer.set_prefix = ('Q')` --> `seqer.set_prefix('Q')` You need function call instead of assignment

Comment: you try to override the method with `obj.method = ('value')` and don't use it `obj.method('value')`. Yuri is right

Comment: Right. Probably some errata in the book's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in these lines -

```
seqer.set_prefix = ('Q');
seqer.set_seq = (1000);
```

```js
var serial_maker = function () {
  var prefix = '';
  var seq = 0;
  
  return {
    set_prefix: function (p) {
      prefix = String(p);
    },
    set_seq: function (s) {
      seq = s;
    },
    gensym: function () {
      var result = prefix + seq;
      seq += 1;
      return result;
    }
  };
};

var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
console.log(seqer.gensym());
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_prefix` and `set_seq`  are functions, so should be called as functions

```js
var serial_maker = function () {
  var prefix = '';
  var seq = 0;
  
  return {
    set_prefix: function (p) {
      prefix = String(p);
    },
    set_seq: function (s) {
      seq = s;
    },
    gensym: function () {
      var result = prefix + seq;
      seq += 1;
      return result;
    }
  };
};

var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
console.log(seqer.gensym());
```